# Equivalent drawing of a parallel basic circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, schematics, parallel, graph

I have the following circuit in Everycircuit:

[image]

Ignoring the component values, when I try plotting this in a network graph, I get something like this:

[image]

Are these two circuits identical? I suppose the one 'confusing' component is the"X" between R2,R3 and R4,R5. (Perhaps a better way to make this would be to have those four 'wires' all meet at a common junction/wiring point.)

R1 = R2 = R3 = R4 = 1,000 ohms

Comment: Hey, the graph is pure nonsense as long as you haven't published anything concrete of what kind of control the wires carry and how a node output depends on the input signals of the same node. Are the wires in the graph possibly bidirectional? I do not claim that it's impossible to find such graph functions that the graph has a kind of equivalence with the presented circuit, but I cannot imagine it. Start by explaining what node R1 gets from node V1 and how R1 exactly decides what it outputs to R2 and R3. Or if the wires are bidirectional you should present for ex. a matrix for every node.

Comment: @user287001 wouldn't the R1 node be defined as 1000 ohms with input current (edge V1R1) = output current( edges R1R2 + R1R3)?

Comment: I see inconsistency in usages and/or definitions in that graph. Why does X1 get its own node but the right side of R1 does not? And the right side of V1 does not? and the left side of GND does not? What makes X1 so different and special?   And why is the lower side of V1 omitted from the GND node entirely? V1 has two terminals where did the other one go? Everything that is the same should be the represented the same way. This is too fast and loose. Everything just means whatever you want it to mean whenever you want to mean it.

Comment: After the question was edited: It's closer now! Add a line between Z and V1, then it's perfect. During the times many  things have evolved to round form for better performance. For example the wheels in the vehicles. Maybe today is the turn of the resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these two circuits identical?

No.

[image]

*Figure 1. The net diagram is missing the node between R1, R2 and R3.*

This seems to be another episode on your strange electrical journey. As mentioned in an answer to your previous post I'm not sure that you'll be able to communicate this stuff with anyone else.