# Converting a schematic to a graph

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics, kirchhoffs-laws

This is a follow up to the question about I posted last night, [Converting a schematic into a graph](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480319/converting-a-schematic-into-a-graph). From some of the answer, I was able to re-work how the graph is done -- with components as edges and connections and nodes. This has been a bit difficult to wrap my head around as normally, I think the inverse:

```
"Mark" is friends with "John" ==> 
    - Mark, John are the nodes; 
    - Mark<->John is the edge
```

But with circuits:

```
"Resistor1" is connected to "Resistor2" (in series) ==>
   - R1R2 is now the node (connection between the two)
   - R1 is an edge, R2 is another edge (assuming a complete circuit)
```

Anyways, I've updated it based on some of the feedback, and now have:

[image]

I've also added the voltage at each of the nodes (though here there is really just one non-trivial node). Does this seem like an improvement on the previous approach, and a better understanding of circuits? What parts still seem to be lacking in this updated diagram? [And thanks to everyone for their encouragement/feedback on previous approaches.]

Comment: Any textbook on circuit theory will go into the graph theory used in circuit analysis. One main difference to your proposal is that we'd consider all the "ground" nodes to be one node, not two. Also, we'd represent the voltage source with a branch from the ground node to the +10 V node.

Comment: @ThePhoton -- thanks. Do you have any suggestions for where I can look into that more: for example a textbook you'd recommend?

Comment: @David542 Just a note with respect to The Photon's comment: I'm sure you are familiar with the DAGs (directed acyclic graphs.) You can "fold" all of the "0 V" nodes to a single node. There is a special requirement, in fact, that ***some*** node in the graph actually ***be*** a 0 V node. The reason is that otherwise all of the node voltages could be any absolute value at all. But it is only the relative voltages that matter. (A voltage ***means*** "from here to there.") So by tying one to 0 V and making all the others relative to that, we make it possible to talk about a voltage "at a node."

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sS6ts.png

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. All grounded points are a single node.*