# Converting a schematic to a graph [part 3]

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, schematics, kirchhoffs-laws

This is part 3 in my journeys to try and graph a basic resistor circuit programmatically ([part 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480319/converting-a-schematic-into-a-graph) and [part 2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480458/converting-a-schematic-to-a-graph). I think I have finally figured out how to treat components -- which if I looked at any existing software to model/calculate circuit I would see that's how they do it. It basically comes down to:

- A component has a fixed number of leads and those leads can be connected at a "connection node" to the leads of other components.

In this way, it's also simple to model something with more than two leads, such as a transistor or other component. Using this approach, here is what I've come up with for my simple resistor circuit:

```
from main import *

# series (node1)
v1=Battery(5)
r1=Resistor(100)

# parallel (node2)
r2=Resistor(200)
r3=Resistor(300)


n=Network()
n.add(v1,r1.IN)
n.add(r1.OUT, r2.IN, r3.IN)
n.ground(all_free=True)
n.graph()
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the library that I'm using to plot the graph is quite poor and inflexible so the graph is anything but intuitive.

Does this updated graph now look accurate as to the circuit it is trying to emulate? If not, what is missing or can be improved (other than the legibility/orientation of the graph)?

And here's the same thing with 20 parallel resistors instead of 2:

[image]

Updated showing the (blue) component as ground and the polarity of the (red) battery so that is more clear:

[image]

Comment: i do not know what can be improved to make the circuit more understandable to you ... perhaps the vertices need to be expanded to line segments

Comment: your post has nothing to do with electronics really ... it is more of a mathematics question or a graphical user interface question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a valid EE question for this site and there is no obvious motivation for making this meaningless mountain from a mole hill.

Answer (score 1):

You're having a lot of trouble being consistent with this project.

[image]

1. Coloured circles seem to be components. Here you have a component with only one lead.
2. Here you have a component with two leads but no identification and no indication of polarity.
3. Here you have a node with four connections. The "proper" schematic shows a maximum of three at any node.

You'll need to handle the power source as a two-lead component with polarity and voltage.

It's not clear how you'll handle even simple components such as a diode.

Comment: thanks for the feedback and taking the time once again to suggest improvements to where I'm at. So a few points of feedback on the pretty non-intuitive graph I have. (1) The "0V" is the ground. It would be similar to this from EveryCircuit: https://imgur.com/a/KOBTTNg. (2) The "+5V" is the battery/voltage source component, the more left/bottom connection is "+" and the part that goes to ground is "-". (3) The node with four connections is just ground, so everything is going to that. Does that help things at all?

Comment: I updated the question with a graph of the updates I made based upon your feedback. Does that seem more clear now?

Comment: (1) Maybe. GND can mean several things. See [Ground, earth and chassis explained](http://lednique.com/ground-earth-chassis/). (2) I think you'll need something a lot more definite to define a voltage source and its polarity. (3) Maybe. But here's a radical suggestion: use a battery or voltage source symbol for the '+5' and an earth symbol for the ground and maybe use a zig-zag line for the resistors. Can you see where this is going?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. `Can you see where this is going?` Yes. Really I've been doing this not so much to create something that's practical but moreso to understand it myself. That is, how a component is connected to another component; how to generate the voltage, current equations, and all that. So yes all the feedback you and others have given is very helpful in terms of creating something that is at least representative of how a basic circuit might work, even if it's a silly/cheap substitute for actual simulators that someone would use for real work.

Comment: also, I think I've updated in the updated screenshot in the question to address #2.

Comment: updated again with orientation and all. https://imgur.com/a/TJ9DZP5

Comment: That's consistent with the schematic.